# Sort array of dictionaries with NSNumbers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have array which has dictionaries. each dictionary is :

```
NSDictionary *imageAndIndex=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:image,[NSNumber numberWithLong:index], nil];
```

Where the object is `image`, and the key is `NSNumber` key made from index.

I want to sort the array according to the `NSNumbers` indexes so it will become:

```
0,1,2,3,4 ..
```

How can i use   `NSSortDescriptor` ?

Comment: this is not the right answer for me so its not a duplicate. here the keys and values are different, there is no one word that describes the key and multiple values, but multiple keys and multiple values.

Comment: You said you wanted to sort the array of dictionaries based on an `NSNumber` key. That is what the duplicate question and its answers does. How is it not a duplicate? What do you wish to do differently?

Comment: DIFFERENT KEYS , AGAIN ?  the keys are not a single word @"key" , but it has differetn words, hence i cant use the NSSortDescriptor because it gets a SINGLE key .

Comment: OK, so it seems I misunderstood your question. It is reopened. You need to update your question with more details. I still don't fully understand what you have and what you want. So far you've shown a single dictionary with only one key. Yet you claim you have multiple keys and values needed for the sort. Show more data. Show more of the result you want and what you have tried.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to have two keys in your dictionary, one named `@"image"` and the other `@"number"` and then sort by `number` using `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` etc? Or perhaps there's a reason you prefer to have only one entry?

Answer (score 3):

The problem (and the debate herein) is complicated by two factors:  1) The OP design choice to sort based on a dictionary key, rather than on a value.  @sooper in comments pointed out correctly that the better design would be to add a @"sortBy" key, whose value is the NSNumber to be sorted.  2) The second complication is the question's reference to NSSortDescriptor, which is going to depend upon values for a given key, not the key itself.

I think the right answer is to take the @sooper suggestion to add @"sortBy" key-value pairs, but if you must sort the data as is...

```
- (void)sortDictionaries {

    NSDictionary *d0 = @{ @0: someUIImage0};
    NSDictionary *d1 = @{ @1: someUIImage1};
    NSDictionary *d2 = @{ @": someUIImage2};

    NSArray *unsorted = @[d1, d2, d0];

    NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
        NSNumber *key1 = [self numericKeyIn:obj1];
        NSNumber *key2 = [self numericKeyIn:obj2];
        return [key1 compare:key2];
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
}

- (NSNumber *)numericKeyIn:(NSDictionary *)d {
    // ps.  yuck.  what do we want to assume here?
    // that it's a dictionary?
    // that it has only one key value pair?
    // that an NSNumber is always one of the keys?

    return [d allKeys][0];
}
```

Not sure why we had to handle this with so much ill-temperment.  It's programming, it's supposed to be fun!

Anyway, here's how you'd do it with a sort key and sort descriptor:

```
- (void)betterSortDictionaries {

    NSDictionary *d0 = @{ @"image":image1, @"sortBy":@0 };
    NSDictionary *d1 = @{ @"image":image2, @"sortBy":@1 };
    NSDictionary *d2 = @{ @"image":image3, @"sortBy":@2 };

    NSArray *unsorted = @[d1, d2, d0];

    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortBy" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];

    NSLog(@"%@", sorted);

}
```